# Changing cells in range based on a range title

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of 25 triggers that have Y or N and the occasional B (for Blocked) for an execution of an automated script.  I have a few different scenarios that I would like to control by setting ranges within the column.  For the example lets call the three by; "ALL", "PARTIAL", and "CUSTOM".

1. I WANT ALL CELLS IN THE RANGE B2:B26 TO BE CHANGED TO "Y" IF THE TRIGGER SETTING CELL OF G2 IS "ALL".
2. I WANT A SUBSET OF 10 CELLS IN THE RANGE B2:B26 TO CHANGE TO "Y" IF THE TRIGGER SETTING CELL OF G2 IS "PARTIAL"
3. I WANT A SUBSET OF CELLS IN THE RANGE B2:B26 TO CHANGE TO "Y" IF THE TRIGGER SETTING CELL OF G2 IS "CUSTOM"

I have tried numerous scenarios without luck.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell what the question is?

Comment: @LarryD Welcome to Super User! Please note that Super User is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is the condition of SUBSET

Comment: Besides previous comments: PLEASE DON'T USE UPPER CASE. Please describe what you've tried and why those aren't good solution for you (not working, error message...). Please add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

In B2 write the following:

```
=IF($G$2="All","Y",IF(AND($G$2="PARTIAL",MOD(ROW(),2)=0),"Y",IF($G$2="CUSTOM","Y","N")))
```

In B3 the Formula below:

```
=IF($G$2="All","Y",IF(AND($G$2="PARTIAL",MOD(ROW(),2)=0,COUNTIF($B$2:B3,"Y")<10),"Y",IF($G$2="CUSTOM","Y","N")))
```

But for Custom you have to decide how many Y and on which condition you can use the countif for partial and decide like the following:

```
=IF($G$2="All","Y",IF(AND($G$2="PARTIAL",MOD(ROW(),2)=0,COUNTIF($B$2:B3,"Y")<10),"Y",IF(and($G$2="CUSTOM",countif($B$2:B3,"Y")<4),"Y","N")))
```